# (ANDROID) Firebase Google SignIn - How to logout from all devices?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want to log out from all devices on the button click for Firebase google login. Is this possible? If yes please share the doc or sample code.

Couldn't find any solution for this on stackoverflow.

Code for LogOut from current device

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
```

This works only for current device & not all devices.

Answer (score 1):

To revoke the refresh tokens for a given user (which will prevent clients requesting a new ID token), you can:

- Change the user's password
- Disable the user using a [Firebase Server SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) and updating the `disabled` property. For Node, you would use the [`Auth#updateUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#updateuser) method of `firebase-admin`.
- Revoke the tokens manually using a [Firebase Server SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens). For Node, you would use the [`Auth#revokeRefreshTokens()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#revokerefreshtokens) method of `firebase-admin`.

It's important to note here, that these methods **won't** invalidate already issued tokens. These tokens will be considered valid up to as long as an hour unless you [explicitly test if they have been revoked](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation). You can deal with this somewhat by using [`FirebaseUser#getIdToken(true)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getIdToken(boolean)) when you detect the user has opened the app but is already signed in. This method tries to get a fresh ID token rather than just use the cached ID token - just make sure to handle the case where the refresh token has been invalidated.

Of the above options, I would recommend the last option and make it available using a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

The server-side code, hosted on Cloud Functions:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

export const revokeRefreshTokens = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-precondition",
      "The function must be called while authenticated."
    );
  }

  // New optional feature: Firebase App Check
  if (context.app === undefined) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-precondition",
      "The function must be called from an App Check verified app."
    );
  }

  const uid = context.auth.uid;

  return admin
    .auth()
    .revokeRefreshTokens(uid)
    .then(() => {
      return admin.auth().getUser(uid);
    })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      // send back a response with the UID and time tokens were revoked
      const timestamp = new Date(userRecord.tokensValidAfterTime).getTime();
      return { uid, revokedAt: timestamp }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // rethrow any errors as HttpsError for clients
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", err.code || err.message);
    });
});
```

The client-side code:

```java
public void revokeRefreshTokens() {
    return FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
        .getHttpsCallable("revokeRefreshTokens")
        .call(data)
        .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Void>() {
            @Override
            public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // revoked successfully, end this sign-in session
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                } else {
                    // failed to revoke, rethrow error
                    throw task.getException();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Revoking the refresh token will prevent the client from minting new ID tokens, but it does not invalidate existing ID tokens. That's why the Firebase documentation shows how to also check in the backend services (such as the database security rules) whether the account has been disabled/signed out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation_in_database_rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That is an important clarification that I did wrongfully skip over. I've added it to the answer.